# How to connect to EC2 instance running asp.net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2

I have a static IP address attached to my ec2 instance and it's running a web server inside a container using asp.net core with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

The debug info says:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80
```

But how can I connect to it in my browser?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, big thanks to this [guy](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/28/external-network-access-to-kestrel-and-iis-express-in-aspnet-core) where I found out Kestrel binds specifically to localhost and I need to explicitly set the url to 0.0.0.0:80 in order to receive outside web traffic. I did this by adding an environment variable (but you can also do cmd line arg) called `ASPNETCORE_URL=0.0.0.0:80`